# Maven: Used dependency in local repository doesn't show parameter name correctly in Javadoc

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

For instance, there is a method in project A:

```
public void putDevice(String deviceId, Device device);
```

I use `mvn install` in order to build project A into a JAR in local Maven repository. With that I can make use of project A's JAR in project B's pom.xml by setting like something like that:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then I can use the method above. However what Intellij IDEA hints is:

[image]

I'd like to see `deviceId` instead of `s` in the picture. How can I get that?

Comment: Have you considered installing an updated Javadoc JAR too?

Comment: Maybe write javadoc with proper param names?